# construct a irreducible subscheme of reducible scheme with funny property

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X= X_1 \cup X_2$ a reducible scheme where $X_i$ are it's irreducible components  and $Y \subset X$ is an irreducible closed subscheme of $X$. I'm looking for a not too artficial example for $X$ and $Y$ with following properties:

For every open subscheme $U \subset X$ with $U \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ (equivalently: $U \cap Y$ is dense in $Y$, because $Y$ irreducible) the both intersections $U \cap X_1, U \cap X_2$ aren't empty.

in other words every open $U$ that intersects $Y$ non trivially, is dense in both irreducible components $X_i$ simultaneously. this is also equivalent to the property that every open $U$ that intersects $Y$ non trivially is not irreducible.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, $X$ the union of two lines crossing and $Y$ the intersection point. But of course your last statement fails to hold.

Comment: the last part of you answer I don't understand. you suggest to consider the "cross" $X:=V(x \cdot y) \subset \mathbb{A}^2=Spec(K[x,y])$ with irreducible decomposion $V(x \cdot y)= V(x) \cup (y)$ and intersection $Y:= V(x,y)$. why in this example you think that my last statement fails to hold? if open $U \subset X$ with $Y \cap U \neq \emptyset$ then $U \cap V(x), U \cap V(y) \neq \emptyset$ and $U= (U \cap V(x)) \cup (U \cap V(y))$ is not irreducible? do I miss something?

Comment: Ah, you are indeed correct.

Comment: In general, one may pick for $Y$ an irreducible component of $X_1\cap X_2$.